# add footer at top of file html

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add a footer in HTML, and I have this lovely function that I made that creates a header for me. I would love to be able to avoid having to type the footer at the end of each document (or call the function at the end of each document), so I would like to use HTML and CSS to have the footer rendered at the bottom but the HTML being coded for it being at the top.

my current layout looks like this

```
<body>
<div id="header">...</div>
<!-- INSERT FOOTER HERE -->
<div id="content">
</body>
```

Comment: why would you add your footer above the content? in that case it's not a footer anymore. Just make that content a part of your header

Comment: @ZoltanToth I think what he wants to do is take some elements that are above the content and display at bottom. It is possible. But if the thing is really a footer, well, I agree with you, that's not the best thing to do...

Comment: So just leave it as it is with the footer at the bottom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kind of a strange request but here you go:

You could use css to position the footer at the bottom. (position:absolute; bottom:0; etc..)

Or you could use javascript to remove the footer and append it to the bottom. (jquery example: $('footer').appendTo('body')).